# “Overstaying” for a bit?

Tags: schengen

I am attending a business workshop in Germany, so I applied and obtained a C-class Geschäftvisum Schengen Visa which is good for a year and 90/180 rule applies.

During the application process, I am asked to submit a business schedule in my application, in which I declared I am staying for 8 days in Germany (a Sun - Sun schedule) with consistent days being filled in the application form as well.

A long friend of mine heard the news that I am coming to Germany and invited me to stay over for a bit. She’s in Schaan, Lichtenstein. With her invitation, I am thinking of extending my stay in the Schengen zone for two days, hence returning to my home country on Tuesday the next week.

So my question is: within the granted condition of my visa, will deviation of my intended day of departure and itinerary get me into trouble?

Comment: What does it say on your visa?

Comment: @Michael Hampton It says **valid from 18/08/19, until 17/08/20, multiple entry, stay up to 90 days.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you follow the requirements printed on your visa (in terms of total days of stay, expiry date, etc.) then you won't be overstaying.

If you stay much longer than you stated in your application, but within the validity period of the visa, this could be taken into account in future visa applications, and cause difficulty. However, two days does not strike me as something that will cause a problem, especially since the main purpose of your visit hasn't changed. Small changes in your itinerary after applying for a visa are normal and acceptable.

In my (non-expert) opinion it seems likely you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I’ll proceed to book corresponding flights then! Out of curiosity though, how would you define **much longer**?

Comment: If you ask for a month and stay two days more, that's not much longer. If you ask for two days and stay a month more, that is. These things aren't fixed in rules - the officer deciding your admission will account for it in the context of everything else they know.

Comment: The OP said that they've been granted a `90 day, multiple entrance visa`, valid for one year. This means that in any rolling 180 day period, the OP can be in the Schengen Area for 90 days. The OP could, if they want, enter for 90 days, leave for 90 days, and then re-enter for 90 days.

Comment: @CSM As I understand it, OP's question isn't so much about the hard limits allowed by the visa, so much as whether they'll have any problems if they stay for longer than claimed on the application. This sort of thing can definitely be an issue in the UK: if you say you're coming for a week, are admitted for 6 months and stay for almost the full 6 months, that might make it harder to get visas in the future.